# Return JSON-object by ID from another JSON

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have 2 API resources:

1. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/appointments with JSON

```
    {
        "id": 771,
        "title": "Call to Alyce Herman - Engine Assembler",
        "assigned_with_person_id": 317,
    }
```

2. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/persons with JSON:

```
    {
        "id": 317,
        "forename": "Lauriane",
        "name": "Jude Greenfelder",
        "oral_coach": 0,
        "coordinator": 0,
        "phone": "+32 2737515",
        "get_organisation": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Sauer-Becker",
            "city": "North Anne",
            "region": "Trinidad and Tobago",
            "street": 0,
            "number": 745,
            "postbox": null,
            "postcode": 26791
        }
    }
```

```
<template>
    <!-- How to put here organization name where are working person (assigned_with_person_id) with ID 317 ? -->
    {{ currentPerson.get_organisation.name }}
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                currentAppointment: {},
                currentPerson: '',
            }
        },

        created () {
            this.axios
            .get(`/api/appointments/${this.$route.params.id}`)
            .then((response) => {this.currentAppointment = response.data;});
        },

        mounted() {
            this.getCurrentPerson();
        },

        methods: {
            getCurrentPerson() {
                
                let personId = /*how to find and put here assigned_with_person_id from JSON of currentAppointment*/;
                
                axios.get(`/api/persons/${personId}`)
                .then(response => (this.currentPerson = response.data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to find get assigned_with_person_id from Appointments-JSON and find this person in Persons-JSON, then put organization name of this person into Vue-template?

Thanks!

Comment: Your endpoints return arrays, right? Please fix your example

Comment: Hi, nope, i need show in Vue-template where are working this person. In first json i know ID of person, in second json i have details of this person. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved with this code:

```
        currentPersonFn() {

            this.axios
//get current Appointment by ID from params
                .get(`/api/appointments/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.currentPID = response.data.assigned_with_person_id; // return only assigned_with_person_id

// put ID of Person into nested axios.get
                    axios.get(`/api/persons/${this.currentPID}`)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.currentPerson = response.data
                            //console.log(response.data)
                        });
                });

        },
```